# In a program if we keep system.exit(0) ,what will happen and what is the console output

Tags: java

i have a progam like this

```
class A {
    public void test1(String s1) {
        try {
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("from finally");
        }
    }

    public void test2(String s2) {
        // some text.....
    }
}
```

In the below class

```
class Manager {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a1 = new A();
        a1.test1("test1");
        a1.test2("test2");
    }
}
```

I want a detailed answer of flow of the program after calling `a1.test1`
control will enter to the `a2.test2` in Manager class or any other? Please clarify my doubt.

Comment: test1 calls exit so the program will terminate at this point.

Comment: Why don't you just try yourself?

Comment: There is no console output of System.exit(). What are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you hit `System.exit(0)` the program is done. It terminates.

Comment: thanks matt i uderstand clearly that the statements before system.exit(0); will exceute and it will terminates the program if we run it and console will get empty(if there any statments before system.exit(0) only executes).

Comment: @Ashok it won't go empty, your entire code stops running.  It's like you closed the program.